# Substract element from array

Tags: ruby

When subtracting arrays I want only the first match to be removed.

E.g.

```
[1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5]-[1,2,3,4] # => [5,5]
```

but I need:

```
[4,4,4,5,5]
```

Another example:

```
[1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5]-[1,2,3,5] # => [4, 4, 4, 4]
```

but result should be:

```
[4,4,4,4,5]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Mukhesh I am done. Please check :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def remove(array, rejects)
  array = array.dup
  rejects.each {|item| array.delete_at(array.index(item))}
  array
end
```

Usage:

```
remove([1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5], [1,2,3,4])                                                                                                                                                                                     
 => [4, 4, 4, 5, 5]                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
remove([1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5], [1,2,3,5])                                                                                                                                                                                     
 => [4, 4, 4, 4, 5]
```

It's left to you to either not call it with incompatible `rejects` or to add error handling to the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, It will work for you.

```
a = [1,2,3,5]
p [1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5].delete_if {|x| a.delete_at(a.index(x)) if a.include? x}
#=> [4, 4, 4, 4, 5]

a = [1,2,3,4]
p [1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5].delete_if {|x| a.delete_at(a.index(x)) if a.include? x}
#=> [4, 4, 4, 5, 5]
```

Some more examples here to clarify the Down-voter:

```
a = [1,2,3,5]
p [3,4,5,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5].delete_if {|x| a.delete_at(a.index(x)) if a.include? x}
#=> [4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]

a = [1,2,4,5]
p [3,4,5,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5].delete_if {|x| a.delete_at(a.index(x)) if a.include? x}
#=> [3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]

a = [2,3,5]
p [3,4,5,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5].delete_if {|x| a.delete_at(a.index(x)) if a.include? x}
#=>[4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]

a = [1,4,4,5]
p [1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5].delete_if {|x| a.delete_at(a.index(x)) if a.include? x}
#=> [2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

Comment: why down-vote? which part not working? It is tested well. **Down-Voter** read carefully what OP asked **When subtracting arrays I want only the first match to be removed**.

Comment: I didn't down-vote your answer, but I do have a few pointers: 1) Your first `a.include? x;` has no side effect and is discarded; you can remove it. 2) Your solution does not correctly handle the case where the second array (your `a`) has duplicate elements, e.g., `a = [1, 4, 4, 5]`. 3) You mutate both arrays, which might not be desirable.

Comment: @DarshanComputing see now,I a bit changed the logic. This was not given by OP thus didn't think. Here in SO we never assume anything what posted, trying to answer accordingly. Still thanks for instructions.

Comment: Nice edits, @RubyLovely. You fixed the first two issues I mentioned, and the third is a minor one that might not matter.

Comment: Thanks Darshan Computing and RubyLovely for your quick reply